# Does Colonel Saito commit suicide?

Tags: character, bridge-on-the-river-kwai

Towards the end of the movie *Bridge on the river Kwai*, the Japanese Colonel writes a letter and cuts off his hair knot on top of his head. Does this mean he eventually plans on committing ritual suicide for reasons of failure and dishonor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to the Bushido code the cutting of ones hair signals a change in life and a lowering of status but not necessarily the act of Hari Kari.

Comment: You may want to add a source to lend your answer credibility.

Comment: Harakiri, not harikari.